# How do I send an ARP packet through python on windows without needing winpcap?

Tags: python, sockets, ethernet, arp

Is there any way to send ARP packet on Windows without the use of another library such as winpcap?

I have heard that Windows XP SP2 blocks raw ethernet sockets, but I have also heard that raw sockets are only blocked for administrators. Any clarification here?

Comment: Should this really be community wiki?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do that in the general case without the use of an external library.

If there are no requirements on what the packet should contain (i.e., if any ARP packet will do) then you *can* obviously send an ARP request if you're on an Ethernet network simply by trying to send something to any IP on your own subnet (ensuring beforehand that the destination IP is not in the ARP cache by running an external `arp -d tar.get.ip.address` command), but this will probably not be what you want.

For more information about raw socket support see the [TCP/IP Raw Sockets Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2), specifically the [Limitations on Raw Sockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN#limitations-on-raw-sockets) section.

Comment: FTR If you do want to use Winpcap/Npcap, there are a few libraries to help with that. Scapy's probably the best when it comes to cross-platform (it also works on Linux/BSD... using other methods)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the OpenVPN tap to send arbitrary packets as if you where using raw sockets.