# Python- ARP Scan without scapy

Tags: sockets, python-3.7, arp

I want to write ARP scanner in `python` without using `scapy`. I know it's easy to perform arp scan using scapy but I don't want to install `winpcap`/`npcap`.
Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/395921/5459467

It is a Windows restriction not to allow access to the layer 2. All you'll have is a copy of the header if you set the options correctly, but it won't allow you to send ARPs.

Winpcap/Npcap works around this by adding a driver below the basic API, where access to level 2 is possible.